# How to serialise an antlr3 AST

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I have just started using antlr3 and am trying to serialize the AST output of a .g grammar.
Thanks,
Lezan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vladimir pointed out, you can use a a custom AST node class that has serialize capabilities builtin.  You could also use a tree adaptor to create the types of nodes you need.

If you only need serialization, and not de-serialization, you could probably just do:

```
ast.toStringTree()
```

The above will give you a LISP like tree structure. An easy way to do serialization would be to use that in combination with a custom AST node class with an overridden `toString()`.  Since `toStringTree()` uses the node's `toStringTree` method, it'll essentially serialize whatever you put in `toString`.  Make its output sufficient and useful and you should be set.

Answer (score 2):

CommonTree nodes produced by Parser are not Serializable.

I'd suggest you to serialize Tokens and use a secondary grammar for parsing the (deserialized) stream of Tokens later. In the book (The Definitive ANTLR Reference), in the Quick Tour for Impatient chapter, Terence Parr gives exactly this scenario -- without serialization though, but serialization is trivial for tokens as they are just text.

My understanding also that you can replace the Tree class with your own:

```
options {
  ASTLabelType = MyOwnTreeClass;
}
```

But I haven't tried it.